# Setting up a kernel driver in Visual Studio

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, driver

Firstly, I am using C and I am using the newest visual studio version and WDK (trying to make a windows 10 driver). When I started my project up I selected Kernel Mode Driver, Empty (KMDF). The issue is I included "ntifs.h" in my class file but its giving me a "cannot open source file "ntifs.h"" error while regular C header include calls works correctly. The ntifs header is a header that should be included in the WDK which I have downloaded which was evident by it allowing me to create an Empty Driver. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Another issue I found was that going into my Drivers properties does not yield the In2Cat and the Linker (trying to access its command line) tab inside of Configuration Properties. I have been searching for the solution to these all day without any luck.

[image]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2022-missing-compatible-wdk/1507277

Comment: @HansPassant So it does not work yet? Which versions do I need to install instead?

Comment: Which version of studio, WDK, and SDK do I need then? Also which individual components do I add (which version) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads?source=recommendations

Also which extension versions do I need (listed next to the visual studio download) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk