# How does vs2022 use the wdk of the old version of vs2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, wdk

I am currently using vs2022 community. But I need to use wdk 2004H.21H2 Build driver win10 cannot be loaded. I want to be able to install and use wdk 2004H on 2022.I have tried installing "WDK for Windows 10 version 2004" directly.sdk version selection 19041 build fails.

How can vs2022 use the 2019 WDK?

I have tried installing "WDK for Windows 10 version 2004" directly.sdk version selection 19041 build fails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186387/setting-up-a-kernel-driver-in-visual-studio

Comment: @HansPassant He had the same problem as me, but the old WDK and SDK didn't work properly with vs2022.